# Validity of Gibbs-Dalton Law

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

I know that the Gibbs-Dalton law valid for an ideal gas mixture of ideal gas components. Does it also hold in the case of ideal gas mixture of real gas components? For example, could I say the pressure or specific heat capacity of the mixture is

$p_{mix}=\sum_{i=1}^Nx_ip_i$

where $p_{mix}$ is the pressure of the mixture, $N$ is the number of components in the mixture, $p_i$ is the partial pressure of component $i$ and $x_i$ is the mole fraction of pure component $i$ in the mixture.

In the case of an ideal gas mixture of ideal gas components, I know this easily follows from the ideal gas law. But what about in the case of ideal gas mixture of real gas components?

For such a mixture, the pure gas components would be considered to be non-reacting and the non-ideal interactions due to mixing would be neglected. It is for this reason I think the answer should be yes but I maybe wrong.

Comment: It's discussed in Wiki's [Raoult's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoult%27s_law) article.

Comment: @lemon From what I understand, the article only compares ideal mixture of ideal gas components against real mixture of real gas components. I am interested in ideal mixtures of real gas components.

Comment: An ideal mixture of real gases obeys the same mixture laws as a mixture of ideal gases, in terms of the relationship between thermodynamic properties in the mixture and those of the pure substances at the same temperature and total pressure.    However, the concept of partial pressure cannot be applied to the constituents of a real gas mixture.  In real (non-ideal) gases, we need to work with fugacities.

Comment: @Chester Could you please provide a link to an article that explains this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't have any links for you.  But, if you are interested in an actual hard copy source, I recommend Chapters 10 and 11 of Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and van Ness.